# Need to define a constant for the string literal[SonarQube Smell]

Tags: java, regex, sonarqube

I need to remove the extra spaces from the string I am getting from JSP.
Before calling the setter method, I am using the below to remove the spaces:

```
class_name=class_name.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").trim();
```

Sonar scan is giving me smell stating define a constant instead of using the literal.
How to put the content in replaceAll parameter in a constant? And use that constant as a parameter.

Sonar scan result :- Define a constant instead of using this "\s{2,}" literal 8 times.

Comment: How are you using this string?  Can you include code which shows this?

Comment: I am getting user input for a field and saving in DB column. I need to have a check which will remove the extra spaces, after the check I am directly calling the setter method. The check is working fine, only issue is the code smell.

Comment: That's something I would ignore (unless you use the same regexp several times).

Comment: Many input fields are there, so finally all of it will get concatenated to form the row entry. That is the reason, I am getting the "multiple times used literal should be a constant" smell.

Comment: @Henry but even then, a method using the literal might be more appropriate.

Comment: @Ragas "I am getting the "multiple times used literal should be a constant" smell" that is a relevant detail that should have been included in the question.

Comment: After your edit, I agree with @AndyTurner, make it a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining constants for string literals (and, sometimes, primitive literals) isn't always helpful.

In this case, it's hard to know what I would call the constant so that it is meaningful and more readable; and you presumably would be encouraged to do the same for both parameters:

```
class_name.replaceAll(TWO_OR_MORE_SPACES_PATTERN, ONE_SPACE_REPLACEMENT).trim()
```

Is that *really* better? I'd say not.

If the problem is that you're using the same replace/trim logic in lots of places, define a method instead:

```
static String replaceSpacesAndStrip(String className) {
  return className.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").trim();
}
```

and then invoke:

```
class_name = replaceSpacesAndStrip(class_name);
```

Comment: 8 Warnings on the same literal, so a method is really in order.